# ScriptManager service reference generates JS code that forgets about the service host name

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax, asmx

I'm working on an ASP.NET project that uses AJAX to communicate with an ASMX web service. One of the pages uses a ScriptManager to reference the web service ASMX file. It's referenced using an absolute URI.

I recently changed both the ASP.NET project and web service to use IIS Express. Each now has a different port number. Since this change, the client-side code for the ASP.NET project can't access the web service.

The generated HTML code for the ASP.NET page contains a correct reference to the web service:

```
<script src="http://localhost:2837/Service.asmx/jsdebug" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, this script only refers back to the web service using a relative URL instead of an absolute one:

```
Service.set_path("/Service.asmx");
```

So AJAX calls to web service methods fail because the hostname from the ASP.NET application is used instead of the web service's:

```
POST http://localhost:2827/Service.asmx/WebServiceMethod 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Notice that the port number above is different to the one used by the web service. The above port number is the one used by the web application.

The HTTP 500 is produced because the web server is reporting:

> *No web service found at: /Service.asmx*

How can I fix this so that the web service is referenced correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Exposing Web Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#sectionToggle1):

> The ServiceReference object can reference a Web service only in the
>   same domain as the page. The Web service path can be relative,
>   application relative, domain relative, or absolute. For absolute
>   paths, you must make sure that the path is in the same domain.

So you can't call your web service method which is in another domain. What you can do is create another service in your asp.net project to call the original web service. then you can call newly created web service method from script manager

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense. It sounds like "domain" depends not only on the host-name, but also the port number. Is that correct?